# Run WSO2IS management console on different server/port

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am learning WSO2 IS 5.4.0 and as a part of requirement, I am asked to run management console on different port than the authentication api e.g oauth2/token or /commonauth etc. I have been searching on official documents and the only thing I found is how to change the default port of the product itself.But my question is:

1. Is it possible to run management console on different port on same embedded tomcat? If yes, where can I find the documentaion for the same?

2.If no, should I block the management console URL in load-balancer to restrict the access from outside network?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> management console on different port than the authentication api e.g oauth2/token or /commonauth

I believe the auth. services inside wso2is uses the same tomcat valve (port) than the managent services (9443) so it would be difficult to separate them

At far I know on wso2am (api manager) the OAuth services (authorize, token, revoke) are as well exposed on the NIO ports (8243, 8280), I am not sure if it's valid for the identity server as well (I believe it's not the case)

> If no, should I block the management console URL in load-balancer to restrict the access from outside network?

we did this and it's working nicely, blocking the `/carbon` and `/services` contexts from the external nework seems as the easiest solution.

imho the cleanest solution from the security perspective would be whitelisting (allowing listed reasources instead if blocking) but we had some heavy UI customization so blocking the mgmt console and admin services was our quick win

Answer (score 0):

I guess could change the port with a port [offset](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Default+Ports+of+WSO2+Products). If you set the port offset to 1 that means port it would listen would be increased by one.